# str_getcsv() file returns all rows in one long array, and fgetcsv() returns only the top header row

Tags: php, csv, import, fgetcsv

I have a file that I saved as a CSV file using Excel (I tried from both Windows 7 and Mac OSX to avoid any compatibility issues).

When I do this:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
$filename = 'import/clientsimport.csv';
$csvfile = file_get_contents($filename);
$csvarray = str_getcsv($csvfile);
print_r($csvarray);
mysql_close();
```

All the rows turn inte one row, and I get an array that is only 1 level deep and runs on and on to the thousands in keys.

So I tried an alternative approach:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
$filename = 'import/clientsimport.csv';
$csvfile = fopen($filename,'r');
$csvarray = fgetcsv($csvfile);
print_r($csvarray);
```

This ONLY returns the 1st row (row of headers) and doesn't go beyond it. How do I do this properly? There are hundreds of rows, and about a dozen arrays per row, so I should be getting a 2 dimensional one.

In the CSV, each row is broken by a linebreak, and values separated by commas - no enclosures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the question by another search with different keywords:

[php str_getcsv array issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099829/php-str-getcsv-array-issue)

Has the answer. Basically I modified my file reading mechanism to:

```
$csvfile = fopen($filename,'rb');
while(!feof($csvfile)) {
$csvarray[] = fgetcsv($csvfile);
}
```

rb I assume is reading with linebreaks? And the while statement loops through the rows. I totally forgot how the fopen works in terms of breaking the content apart and having to loop through, unlike file_get_contents() which returns one long string only.

Comment: The above is not working really and throws *Warning: str_getcsv() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given*

Comment: The proposed solution works if altered the way Norseman Bjørne suggested in his answer.

Comment: 'rb' means "read binary", which essentially means that php just reads the bytes without trying to interpret them as, say, characters.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
$multiarray = array();
while ($linearray = fgetcsv($cvsfile)) {
   $multiarray[] = $linearray;
}
```