# PHP CSV string to array

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I'm trying to parse a CSV string to an array in PHP. The CSV string has the following attributes:

```
Delimiter: ,
Enclosure: "
New line: \r\n
```

Example content:

```
"12345","Computers","Acer","4","Varta","5.93","1","0.04","27-05-2013"
"12346","Computers","Acer","5","Decra","5.94","1","0.04","27-05-2013"
```

When I try to parse it like this:

```
$url = "http://www.url-to-feed.com";
$csv = file_get_contents($url);
$data = str_getcsv($csv);
var_dump($data);
```

The last and first element are concatenated in one string:

```
[0]=> string(5) "12345"
...
[7]=> string(4) "0.04"
[8]=> string(19) "27-05-2013
"12346""
```

How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `[2]=> string(48) "Acer"`, `Acer` definitely is not 48 chars long. You may want to inspect your input if it really is in proper format.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Do this:

```
$csvData = file_get_contents($fileName);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
print_r($array);
```

It will give you an output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12345
            [1] => Computers
            [2] => Acer
            [3] => 4
            [4] => Varta
            [5] => 5.93
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 0.04
            [8] => 27-05-2013
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12346
            [1] => Computers
            [2] => Acer
            [3] => 5
            [4] => Decra
            [5] => 5.94
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 0.04
            [8] => 27-05-2013
        )

)
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: I'm legitimately curious, but is there a reason why this would be better than Gaui's simple one-line solution below, or are people just upvoting this because it's the selected answer?

Comment: Thanks, It's also working when My csv file has content with comma "Martin T," and double quotation like => Philipp "Heinzelmann"

Comment: This fails for multiline CSV fields

Comment: This can cause a rare problem, if you have a newline contained inside a value, then the `PHP_EOL` splits the value into 2 different array values.

Comment: After searching for an hour, your solution worked! Thank you very much. I tried the array mapping to str_getcsv, but it couldn't handle the new line characters INSIDE the field.

Comment: fails if there is a comma in any of the fields

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this fails if there is a comma in any of the fields as @hyphenthis noted?

Comment: It would not fail if there's a comma inside the field, so long as the field is properly enclosed. If it's not enclosed, then the file is malformed, and no CSV-reader will parse it properly. But it will fail if there is a newline inside a field, as noted by @SebastianMach.

Comment: My answer below will NOT fail on newline inside the field.

Comment: Use `fgetcsv()` only! Because `explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData)` don't parse line breaks in csv strings correctly! See the right answer below.

Answer (score 61):

**You should use fgetcsv.**  Since you cannot import a file as a stream because the csv is a variable, then you should spoof the string as a file by using `php://temp` or `php://memory` first:

```
$fp = fopen("php://temp", 'r+');
fputs($fp, $csvText);
rewind($fp);
```

Then you will have no problem using fgetcsv:

```
$csv = [];
while ( ($data = fgetcsv($fp) ) !== FALSE ) {
    $csv[] = $data;
}
fclose($fp)
```

`$data` will be an array of a single csv line (which may include line breaks or commas, etc), as it should be.

Caveat: The memory limit of php://temp can be controlled by appending /maxmemory:NN, where NN is the maximum amount of data to keep in memory before using a temporary file, in bytes. (the default is 2 MB) http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: This is one of the few answers that actually properly handles newlines inside of fields.. it should have far more upvotes.

Comment: This is the best way! Don't use `file('data.csv')` or `explode(PHP_EOL, $csv)` because they don't parse line breakes in csv strings correctly!

Comment: How does it distinguish between a newline inside a field and a newline constituting line/record delimiter?

Comment: I'm guessing it does this by figuring out if the line break is wrapped in the enclosure (usually `"`) and treating it appropriately.

Comment: This is the more proper way, the accepted answer is a quick way but doesn't cover multi lines in the fields

Comment: The memory limit of php://temp can be controlled by appending /maxmemory:NN, where NN is the maximum amount of data to keep in memory before using a temporary file, in bytes.  (the default is 2 MB) https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php - thanks, steven!

Comment: I think `fclose($fp)` should be added at the end.

Answer (score 37):

Handy oneliner:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
```

Comment: Fails for multiline CSV fields, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes probably, because file() would mistake it for a new CSV row.

Comment: Won't be able to handle new lines inside fields. The accepted answer solves for that with PHP_EOL. Good if you don't have new lines I suppose. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Should credit the author of this handy one liner: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php (see first comment)

Comment: @WebmasterG, using `PHP_EOL` will not solve for the newlines inside of fields issue. The accepted answer fails with this just as if `\n` was used instead. `PHP_EOL` is actually the wrong solution here, because it will use the EOL character of the platform running PHP, not of the platform that built the CSV file.

Comment: Use `fgetcsv()` only! Because `file('data.csv')` don't parse line breaks in csv strings correctly! See the right answer below.

Comment: This is perfect if the csv file is comma separated, but what if the file is semicolon ";" separated??  I use this code and works fine, but just now I have a semicolon separated file and it's not working.

Comment: @Alex in the documentation of the method https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php there are details on how to change the delimiter (to use semicolon instead of commas, for instance), as well as the enclosure and escape. So the method is equally valid, only that you need to dig a bit more and read the documentation. PHP documentation is quite nicely written, and has tones of examples.

Answer (score 10):

I have used following function to parse csv string to associative array

```
public function csvToArray($file) {
    $rows = array();
    $headers = array();
    if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)) {
        $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $row = fgetcsv($handle, 10240, ',', '"');
            if (empty($headers))
                $headers = $row;
            else if (is_array($row)) {
                array_splice($row, count($headers));
                $rows[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        throw new Exception($file . ' doesn`t exist or is not readable.');
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

if your csv file name is mycsv.csv then you call this function as:

```
$dataArray = csvToArray(mycsv.csv);
```

you can get this script also in http://www.scriptville.in/parse-csv-data-to-array/

Comment: This is the best solution so far!

Since I am using Excel CSV, I have changed this line

`$row = fgetcsv($handle, 10240, ',', '"');`

to

`$row = fgetcsv($handle, 10240, ';', '"');`

Answer (score 3):

Slightly shorter version, without unnecessary second variable:

```
$csv = <<<'ENDLIST'
"12345","Computers","Acer","4","Varta","5.93","1","0.04","27-05-2013"
"12346","Computers","Acer","5","Decra","5.94","1","0.04","27-05-2013"
ENDLIST;

$arr = explode("\n", $csv);
foreach ($arr as &$line) {
  $line = str_getcsv($line);
}
```

Comment: Fails for multiline fields.

Answer (score 3):

A modification of previous answers using `array_map`.
Blow up the CSV data with multiple lines.

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', explode("\n", $csvData));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's working for me:

```
$delimiter = ",";
  $enclosure = '"';
  $escape = "\\" ;
  $rows = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $content));
  $header = NULL;
  $data = [];

  foreach($rows as $row)
  {
    $row = str_getcsv ($row, $delimiter, $enclosure , $escape);

    if(!$header) {
      $header = $row;
    } else {
      $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
  }
```

Comment: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements, how can I correct and checking if I have the same quantity, they are 2 associative arrays

Answer (score 0):

If you need a name for the csv columns, you can use this method

```
 $example= array_map(function($v) {$column = str_getcsv($v, ";");return array("foo" => $column[0],"bar" => $column[1]);},file('file.csv'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have carriage return/line feeds within columns, str_getcsv will not work.

Try https://github.com/synappnz/php-csv

Use:

```
include "csv.php";
$csv = new csv(file_get_contents("filename.csv"));
$rows = $csv->rows();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  // do something with $row
}
```