# PHP - Unable to parse CSV String into array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, csv

I am having trouble parsing CSV String into multi dimensional array. I already seen this question [PHP CSV string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761172/php-csv-string-to-array) But i do not get the same result..

The CSV when printed on the screen looks like this:

> Agent,Answered,Missed,Contribution,Per Hour,Total Ring Time,Mean Ring Time,Total Talk Time,Mean Talk Time,Total Wrap Time,Mean Wrap Time,Total Session Time,Mean Session Time,Number of Sessions,% Util,Agent Hang-Ups,Caller Hang-Ups,Agent Hang-Ups Percent,Caller Hang-Ups Percent Amber,16,0,2.0%,0.2,28.6,1.8,1861.1,116.3,0.0,0.0,234862.2,3403.8,69.0,0.8%,10,6,62.5%,37.5% Amie,106,0,13.5%,3.0,721.7,6.8,12268.0,115.7,0.0,0.0,127011.0,6350.5,20.0,9.7%,54,52,50.9%,49.1% Andrew S,4,0,0.5%,0.1,0.0,0.0,1495.6,373.9,46.9,11.7,216218.4,3793.3,57.0,0.7%,2,2,50.0%,50.0% Catherine,28,0,3.6%,0.7,55.3,2.0,3089.4,110.3,0.0,0.0,135318.2,1409.6,96.0,2.3%,14,14,50.0%,50.0% David S,63,0,8.0%,2.0,393.0,6.2,6429.6,102.1,0.0,0.0,113765.5,16252.2,7.0,5.7%,20,43,31.7%,68.3% James,10,0,1.3%,0.1,3.4,0.3,1796.5,179.7,0.0,0.0,258600.0,3747.8,69.0,0.7%,2,8,20.0%,80.0% Jo,20,0,2.5%,0.2,120.0,6.0,3753.3,187.7,0.0,0.0,454249.4,7699.1,59.0,0.8%,9,11,45.0%,55.0% Jodie,37,0,4.7%,0.7,39.9,1.1,3570.5,96.5,0.0,0.0,204273.4,3462.3,59.0,1.7%,21,16,56.8%,43.2% Joe,16,0,2.0%,0.3,15.2,1.0,1847.0,115.4,0.0,0.0,219218.5,4059.6,54.0,0.8%,3,13,18.8%,81.3% Josh,11,0,1.4%,0.2,9.7,0.9,1892.3,172.0,0.0,0.0,209009.6,2714.4,77.0,0.9%,2,9,18.2%,81.8% LINE,11,0,1.4%,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0%,11,0,100.0%,0.0% Lee,67,0,8.5%,1.1,277.4,4.1,18616.5,277.9,44091.7,658.1,223320.1,5726.2,39.0,8.3%,45,22,67.2%,32.8% Local/5201@callback-agent,108,91,13.7%,0.3,672.7,3.4,11262.9,104.3,0.0,0.0,1209599.0,1209599.0,1.0,0.9%,35,73,32.4%,67.6% Local/5294@callback-agent,21,7,2.7%,0.1,161.7,5.8,1290.6,61.5,0.0,0.0,1209599.0,1209599.0,1.0,0.1%,11,10,52.4%,47.6% Local/5309@callback-agent,24,0,3.1%,0.1,0.0,0.0,4452.1,185.5,0.0,0.0,1209599.0,1209599.0,1.0,0.4%,8,16,33.3%,66.7% Local/5400@callback-agent,23,16,2.9%,1.5,208.8,5.4,997.3,43.4,0.0,0.0,54625.7,13656.4,4.0,1.8%,8,15,34.8%,65.2% Local/5402@callback-agent,12,0,1.5%,22.0,107.4,8.9,555.7,46.3,0.0,0.0,1960.0,1960.0,1.0,28.4%,5,7,41.7%,58.3% Local/5415@callback-agent,5,1,0.6%,0.0,76.6,12.8,221.2,44.2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0%,1,4,20.0%,80.0% Maddie,38,0,4.8%,0.6,91.0,2.4,5743.0,151.1,0.0,0.0,212379.5,2469.5,86.0,2.7%,9,29,23.7%,76.3% Mel,9,0,1.1%,0.2,4.4,0.5,1340.5,148.9,0.0,0.0,197666.8,3137.6,63.0,0.7%,4,5,44.4%,55.6% Paul M,56,0,7.1%,0.1,241.0,4.3,15575.1,278.1,0.0,0.0,3982747.0,3982747.0,1.0,0.4%,34,22,60.7%,39.3% Shane,13,0,1.7%,0.2,10.9,0.8,2244.3,172.6,0.0,0.0,214092.8,3398.3,63.0,1.0%,0,13,0.0%,100.0% Tony C,7,0,0.9%,0.1,36.2,5.2,1052.8,150.4,0.0,0.0,179391.7,1812.0,99.0,0.6%,3,4,42.9%,57.1% Vanessa,11,0,1.4%,0.0,56.3,5.1,608.8,55.3,0.0,0.0,1209599.0,1209599.0,1.0,0.1%,5,6,45.5%,54.5% Vic ,70,0,8.9%,0.0,486.2,6.9,9044.4,129.2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0%,27,43,38.6%,61.4% "

Which pretty much seems like one liner. However when i export this data to a file and open with i.e. Excel the data is nicely formatted.

How it looks in Excel 
[image]

However before i can send it to a file i need to manipulate it and to do that i wanted to change it into an array. However when do:

```
$test = explode(",", $csvString);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($test); echo '</pre>';
```

What i get is not exactly what i want. I would like to get Multidimensional array but what i get is a single array, which just names in between.

Output OLD METHOD:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ï»¿Agent
    [1] => Answered
    [2] => Missed
    [3] => Contribution
    [4] => Per Hour
    [5] => Total Ring Time
    [6] => Mean Ring Time
    [7] => Total Talk Time
    [8] => Mean Talk Time
    [9] => Total Wrap Time
    [10] => Mean Wrap Time
    [11] => Total Session Time
    [12] => Mean Session Time
    [13] => Number of Sessions
    [14] => % Util
    [15] => Agent Hang-Ups
    [16] => Caller Hang-Ups
    [17] => Agent Hang-Ups Percent
    [18] => Caller Hang-Ups Percent
Amber
    [19] => 16
    [20] => 0
    [21] => 2.0%
    [22] => 0.2
    [23] => 28.6
    [24] => 1.8
    [25] => 1861.1
    [26] => 116.3
    [27] => 0.0
    [28] => 0.0
    [29] => 234862.2
    [30] => 3403.8
    [31] => 69.0
    [32] => 0.8%
    [33] => 10
    [34] => 6
    [35] => 62.5%
    [36] => 37.5%
```

OUTPUT Second Method:

```
    // Curls stuff above, to access the file 
    // Curl accesses the correct path to the url and save is in a variable.
    // Session at this point is still open 

    $csvData = file_get_contents($url);
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
    $array = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }
    var_dump($array);

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
```

Output Using above method

```
    var_dump
    array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "ï»¿" } }

    echo
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => ï»¿
            )
     )
```

**EDIT**
**At the end, after moving code around and double checking everything it turned out that instead of pointing to a variable i was pointing to a method ...**

Expected output

```
Array
(    
    [0] => Agent 
    (
        [0] => Answered
        [1] => Missed
        [2] => Contribution
        [3] => Per Hour
        [4] => Total Ring Time
        [5] => Mean Ring Time
        [6] => Total Talk Time
        [7] => Mean Talk Time
        [8] => Total Wrap Time
        [9] => Mean Wrap Time
        [10] => Total Session Time
        [11] => Mean Session Time
        [12] => Number of Sessions
        [13] => % Util
        [14] => Agent Hang-Ups
        [15] => Caller Hang-Ups
        [16] => Agent Hang-Ups Percent
        [17] => Caller Hang-Ups Percent
    )
    [1] => Amber 
    (
        [0] => 16
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 2.0%
        [3] => 0.2
        [4] => 28.6
        [5] => 1.8
        [6] => 1861.1
        [7] => 116.3
        [8] => 0.0
        [9] => 0.0
        [10] => 234862.2
        [11] => 3403.8
        [12] => 69.0
        [13] => 0.8%
        [14] => 10
        [15] => 6
        [16] => 62.5%
        [17] => 37.5%
    )
    .... ETC
```

Comment: Please post the code of what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried to use function [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)?

Comment: @machineaddict if you would take time to actually read the whole thing you will see that there is a code sufficient for this example :)

Comment: There is only `$test = explode(",", $csvString);` and you printed it out. I was reffering to the actual code that you have tried. A try to transform one array into the other one. And use `fgetcsv` function like marian0 pointed out.

Comment: @machineaddict well the rest of the code is not really relevant. I do have some curl above to access the file. The file content is saved as a single string in a variable. I have also updated my questions showing what happens when i try to access the file directly and not as a string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are NOT doing what is being shown in the very example that you quoted. In that example, the file is read, is exploded first on EOL to get individual lines, then each line is individually exploded on ',' to get the multidimensional array ... what's wrong in that code?

And just exploding on ',' to parse out the fields in CSV file is plain wrong. There are many nuances in that. e.g. the comma may be embedded in a field.

Comment: Sorry i have included wrong link, but anyway i have tried to do it the same way as the answer provided in a link, yet this actually has some trouble parsing the data alltogether for some reason

Comment: doing what the example quoted by you did is not hard. Get the file, explode on EOL, iterate over lines, explode each line, parse each line. Please do this code and then I can help.

Comment: Ok can be closed i had a typo all the time that was not referring to what it should be... instead of referring to variable at the end i was pointing to a method ...