# Input CSV File and upload it to MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

**Edit2:**

Well i found a solution that works for me, the string will be saved in $v[0][0], [1][0], [2][0] ... still not perfekt, but i should work that way.

Code: (Delimiters: ";" and "\n")

```
$csvData = file_get_contents("data.csv");
$lines = preg_split("/[\n,;]+/", $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach($lines as $line){ $array[]= str_getcsv($line);}
```

**Edit:**
Save the CSV to a array would solve my problem, i would use the indexes from the array in the sql insert.

I tried following codes, but it doesnt work for me...

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
```

.

```
$csvData = file_get_contents($fileName);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
$array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
print_r($array);
```

When i echo $array[0][0] it shows the HOWL line. I really dont get it...the second one is the top answer here: [PHP CSV string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761172/php-csv-string-to-array)

***I have to upload a csv file like this:***

- category;question;a1;a2;a3;a4
- 1;question;a1;a2;a3;a4
- 2;question;a1;a2;a3;a4
- 2;question;a1;a2;a3;a4

Now i have to add this questions to my questions table, my problem is that every category starts at a specific id: cat 1 start at 1, cat 2 at 1000, cat 3 at 2000 ...

E.g: The last question with category 2 has the id 1012, so the questions with cat 2 from the csv file need to be inserted at 1013 and 1014.

My idea is that before i insert the csv, i count the number of rows from each category an then insert the IDs manually. (e.g: cat 2 has 12 rows, + 1001 would be the id for the first new question)

Has anyone a idea how i could get that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just load the CSV to another table.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
INTO TABLE tmp_table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
;
```

- read more about this command [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Then calculate the `id` in the `insert` statement.

```
INSERT INTO questions (id, cat, question, a1, a2, a3, a4)
SELECT 
cat - 1 + 1000 + sq.number as id,
cat, question, a1, a2, a3, a4
FROM tmp_table_name t
JOIN (SELECT cat, count(*) as number FROM tmp_table_name GROUP BY cat) sq
ON t.cat = sq.cat
```

P.S.: Column names like a1, a2, a3 and a4 (I assume a is short for answer?) smells like very bad database design. Put the answers in a separate table and in one column.

```
Table questions:
id
cat
questionId
question
answers
```

---

```
Table answers:
questionId
answer
```

The tables are linked via questionId