# Reading csv data file with c3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, c3.js

As a new web developer, I would like to visualize csv data from c3.js.
I have looked into their examples, and succeeded so far with data entered manually by hand as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Visualisation test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <link href="libs/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="libs/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/c3.min.js"></script>
</head>

  <body>
  <p> <b> The chart is displayed below: </b> </p>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script> 

    var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50, 130, 100, 140, 200],            
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5
        }
    },
   axis: {rotated : true}
});

    </script>
  <p> End of Chart </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But reading the data from a csv file doesn't display anything.
The way I did was by remplacing the data section with the following code:

```
data: {
        url: '/path/to/my/file.csv',
        type: 'line'
    }
```

My CSV file content:

```
data1,data2
120,80
140,50
170,100
150,70
180,120
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the issue. Just make sure to disable ad blockers extensions ...

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a problem with your path, because your snippet is the correct way to load an external CSV file into C3:

```
data: {
    url: 'data.csv',
    type: 'bar'
},
```

This is a plunkr with your code, and your data is loaded from a CSV file, check it: https://plnkr.co/edit/moRdOmyeMkb533XJHyoY?p=preview

This is the documentation: http://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html

Comment: Indeed. As you can see, the Plunker works with an external CSV. Does your path go to another domain?

Comment: absolutely not. my path is 'data.csv' and the file is in the same folder.

Answer (score -3):

You could read the file using PHP:

[PHP CSV string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761172/php-csv-string-to-array)

then json_encode the output and use it in your columns array.